# PHP find closest specific day to date

Tags: php

I'm writing a script that gets some statistics about my website for a date this year, but I also want it to get me the data for the nearest corresponding day last year so I can compare them.

For example if I were to get the data for "Wednesday 14th Dec 2011", I'd want to also get the data for "Wednesday 15th Dec 2010".

I'm having a bit of trouble thinking of how to get the correct date from this year's date. I'd prefer to be able to pass the data into a function, something like:

```
// $date as a unix timestamp
// $day (0 for Sunday through 6 for Saturday)
function getClosestDay($date,$day=0) {

}
```

So I would be passing in a unix timestamp of last year's date, and also the day I'm looking to find. I'd expect it to return a unix timestamp of the correct day.

But I'm not sure where to even start with the function.

I'm not looking for someone to write the function for me, but if anyone has any ideas on where to start (even a nudge in the right direction) then that would be great!

Comment: `Monday 14th Dec 2011`, can you explain this? According to the clock in my Mac, is Wednesday.

Comment: Yeah, I got my date wrong, apologies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this would do. First we get the unix time of the same day last year

```
$newDate = '14th Dec 2011';
$newDate = strtotime($newDate);
$oldDate = strtotime('-1 year',$newDate);
```

Now we find the difference in week day. In this example, it'll be -1

```
$newDayOfWeek = date('w',$oldDate);
$oldDayOfWeek = date('w',$newDate);
$dayDiff = $oldDayOfWeek-$newDayOfWeek;
```

And then we extract/add that difference to the date

```
$oldDate = strtotime("$dayDiff days",$oldDate);
```

And output it

```
print date('r',$oldDate)."\n";
print date('r',$newDate)."\n";
```

The above should yield

```
Wed, 15 Dec 2010 00:00:00 +0100
Wed, 14 Dec 2011 00:00:00 +0100
```

Comment: Awesome - working out the difference seems like the best approach! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with:

```
function getClosestDate($date, $day = 0, $year = -1) {
    $cts = strtotime($date);
    $ts = strtotime("{$year} YEAR", $cts);

    $days = array(
        'Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday',
    );
    $day = $days[$day];

    $prev = strtotime("PREVIOUS {$day}", $ts);
    $next = strtotime("NEXT {$day}", $ts);

    $prev_gap = $ts - $prev;
    $next_gap = $next - $ts;

    return $prev_gap < $next_gap ? $prev : $next;
}

echo date('Y-m-d', getClosestDate('2011-12-12', 1));
// prints 2010-12-13 (closest Monday to 2010-12-12)

echo date('Y-m-d', getClosestDate('2011-12-12', 4));
// prints 2010-12-09 (closest Thursday to 2010-12-12)
```

And by the way (and fortunately), December 14th 2011 is not a Monday. :)

Comment: haha, clearly I looked at the wrong day on the calender there...!

Answer (score 1):

I got it, here it goes:

```
function getClosestDay($date) {
    $w = date("w", strtotime("-1 year", $date));
    $week = date("w", $date);
    $days = ($week - $w);

    return date("Y-m-d l", strtotime($days . " days -1 year", $date));
}
```

echo getClosestDay(mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 14, 2011));

Comment: Again, if I did that then passing in "Monday 14th Dec 2011" would return me "Tuesday 14th Dec 2010", which isn't what I want. I want The Closest Monday (or any other day I choose to put in the function) to that date.

Comment: Now it works, although I like netcoder and Kristian Antonsen's method better - so I can choose the day if required. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getClosestDay($date,$day=0) {
  $days = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
  return strtotime('last ' . $days[$day], $date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less elegant but tested function :

```
function getClosestDay($time,$dayOfTheWeek) {
    $last_year=strtotime("last year",$time);
    $next=strtotime("next $dayOfTheWeek",$last_year);
    $last=strtotime("previous $dayOfTheWeek",$last_year);

    $most_near = (min($next-$last_year,$last_year-$last) == ($next-$last_year)) ? $next : $last;

    return $most_near;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried strtotime?

`strtotime('-1 year',time());`

Comment: That would find me the same date last year. I want the closest of the same day to the same date last year. As my example above states: if I were to get the data for "Monday 14th Dec 2011", I'd want to also get the data for "Monday 13th Dec 2010".

Comment: -1 year 1 day wouldn't work, it's not always -1 year 1 day, that completely depends on the date being passed in.